# $\frac ab<\frac cd<\frac ef$ ($a,b,c,d,e,f\in\Bbb N$); $af-be=-1$; show that $d\ge b+f$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

$$\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}<\frac{e}{f} (a,b,c,d,e,f \in \Bbb{N})$$

If $af-be=-1$, show that $d \geq b+f$

I don't know how to proceed. Whichever way I go, I'm unable to use the equality. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$af-be=-1$ is equivalent to $$\frac e f -\frac a b=\frac 1 {bf}$$
Now note that 
\begin{align}
\frac 1 {bf} & =\frac e f -\frac a b\\
& =\left(\frac c d-\frac a b\right)+\left(\frac e f -\frac c d\right)\\
& =\frac{bc-ad}{bd}+\frac{de-cf}{df}\\
& \ge \frac{1}{bd}+\frac{1}{df}
\end{align}
Which simplifies to $d\ge b+f$. The last inequality holds since $bc-ad>0$ and is an integer, thus is least $1$, and the same for $de-cf$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $bc − ad > 0,$ we have $bc − ad ≥ 1$. Similarly, we obtain $de − f c ≥ 1$.

Therefore

$d = d(be − af) = dbe − daf = dbe − bf c + bf c − adf = b(de − f c) + f(bc − ad) ≥ b + f.$