# An olympiad inequality problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> - Let $\displaystyle{a, b, c, d, e, f}$ be positive integers such that
>     $\displaystyle{{a \over b} < {c \over d} < {e \over f}}$.
> - Also $\displaystyle{af - be = -1}$.

Show that $\displaystyle{d \geq b + f}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\frac{a}{b}\lt\frac{c}{d}\lt\frac{e}{f}$ ($a,b,c,d,e,f \in \Bbb{N})$ If $af-be=-1$, show that $d \geq b+f$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970992/fracab-fraccd-fracef-a-b-c-d-e-f-in-bbbn-if-af-be-1)

Comment: @FelixMarin When a post is put on hold, the first edit after that [puts it into reopen review queue](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16820/should-i-avoid-minor-edit-of-a-question-which-was-put-on-hold/16821#16821). Since your edit only changed formatting, I do not think that it will change whether users see the question as *missing context* so the likely result of [the reopen review](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/701073) will be to leave it closed. Therefore I hink it is better to edit post, which is on hold, only if the edit sufficiently addresses closure reason.

Comment: ...I will admit that in this case it is not much a of a problem, since there is a duplicate. (So it does not matter too much whether it is closed as a duplicate or for missing context.) But in general, I think it is good to follow the above advice.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for your remark. I was not aware of that. I just did it because the reading was not pleasant to me. Every day we learn something new. I'll keep your info$\ldots$ for the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This inequality can be used to show the goodness of continued fraction approximations.

The given equation, $af-be=-1$, implies
$$
\frac ef-\frac ab=\frac1{bf}\tag{1}
$$
Since $\frac cd\gt\frac ab$, we must have
$$
\frac cd-\frac ab\ge\frac1{bd}\tag{2}
$$
Since $\frac ef\gt\frac cd$, we must have
$$
\frac ef-\frac cd\ge\frac1{df}\tag{3}
$$
Therefore, adding $(2)$ and $(3)$ and comparing $(1)$ gives
$$
\frac1{bf}\ge\frac1{bd}+\frac1{df}\tag{4}
$$
which simplifies to
$$
d\ge b+f\tag{5}
$$